# Send email to all users in a MySQL database

Tags: mysql, bash, email

I can query our MySQL database to get the email address of all registered user accounts. I want to send an email to every user, one by one.

### Query

```
SELECT email FROM users
```

### Output

```
email
-------
email@domain.com
email@domain.com
email@domain.com
```

### Email

```
cat <<EOF | sendmail -t
To: %%u.email%%
Subject: Testing
From: sender@example.com

This is a test message
EOF
```

How can I use the email addresses returned from the MySQL database instead of `%%u.email%%`?

Answer (score 0):

Giving you have defined sendmail and query scripts:

```
while read -r email; do ./sendmail "${email}"; done < <(./query | head -n +2)
```